# WebServerInstance Encountered unsupported property VpcId

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I keep getting this issue in the Webserversinstance.

```
*Paramaters*
    VPCSelection": {
          "Description": "VPC",
          "Type": "String",
          "Default": "vpc-xxxxxxx"

*Webserver Security group*
    "Resources": {
        "WebServerSecurityGroup": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
          "Properties": {
            "VpcId": {
              "Ref": "VPCSelection"
            },

*WebServer Instance*
{
  "Resources": {
    "WebServerSecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPCSelection"
        },
```

When i run this template, i get this issue:

```
12:45:52 UTC+0000 ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Test13 The following resource(s) failed to create: [WebServerInstance]. . Rollback requested by user. 


12:45:51 UTC+0000 CREATE_FAILED AWS::EC2::Instance WebServerInstance Encountered unsupported property VpcId
```

When i remove this VPCid from the webserver instance i get a different error saying:  `AWS::EC2::Instance WebServerInstance No default VPC for this user`

Comment: Please checkout this question and answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439206/create-an-ec2-instance-for-a-vpc-not-allowed

Comment: Thanks! really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I put this into Bisque and got the below.  Does this help?

```
    {
      "Resources": {
        "WebServerSecurityGroup": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
          "Metadata": {
            "YadaYada::Bisque::DotnetType": {
              "Type": "Bisque.EC2.Networking.SecurityGroup, Bisque.Aws, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
            }
          },
          "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription": {
              "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroupGroupDescription"
            },
            "VpcId": {
              "Ref": "VPCSelection"
            },
            "Tags": [
              {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "WebServerSecurityGroup"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "WebServerInstance": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
          "Metadata": {
            "YadaYada::Bisque::DotnetType": {
              "Type": "Bisque.EC2.Instances.Instance, Bisque.Aws, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
            },
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
              "configSets": {
                "Bootstrap": [
                  "Bootstrap"
                ]
              },
              "Bootstrap": {
                "services": {
                  "windows": {
                    "cfn-hup": {
                      "ensureRunning": true,
                      "enabled": true,
                      "files": [
                        "c:\\cfn\\hooks.d\\cfn-auto-reloader.conf",
                        "c:\\cfn\\cfn-hup.conf"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                "files": {
                  "c:\\cfn\\hooks.d\\cfn-auto-reloader.conf": {
                    "content": {
                      "Fn::Join": [
                        "\n",
                        [
                          "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]",
                          "triggers=post.update",
                          "path=Resources.WebServerInstance.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init",
                          {
                            "Fn::Join": [
                              "",
                              [
                                "action=",
                                {
                                  "Fn::Join": [
                                    "",
                                    [
                                      "cfn-init.exe -v -c \"",
                                      "Bootstrap",
                                      "\" -s ",
                                      {
                                        "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                                      },
                                      " -r WebServerInstance --region ",
                                      {
                                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  ]
                                }
                              ]
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "c:\\cfn\\cfn-hup.conf": {
                    "content": {
                      "Fn::Join": [
                        "\n",
                        [
                          "[main]",
                          {
                            "Fn::Join": [
                              "",
                              [
                                "stack=",
                                {
                                  "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                                }
                              ]
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "Fn::Join": [
                              "",
                              [
                                "region=",
                                {
                                  "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                }
                              ]
                            ]
                          },
                          "interval=1",
                          "verbose=true"
                        ]
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "Properties": {
            "SecurityGroupIds": [
              {
                "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"
              }
            ],
            "Tags": [
              {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "WebServerInstance"
              }
            ],
            "ImageId": {
              "Ref": "WebServerInstanceImageId"
            },
            "InstanceType": {
              "Ref": "WebServerInstanceInstanceType"
            },
            "KeyName": {
              "Ref": "WebServerInstanceKeyName"
            },
            "UserData": {
              "Fn::Base64": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                  "",
                  [
                    "<script>",
                    {
                      "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                          "cfn-init.exe -v -c \"",
                          "Bootstrap",
                          "\" -s ",
                          {
                            "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                          },
                          " -r WebServerInstance --region ",
                          {
                            "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                          }
                        ]
                      ]
                    },
                    "</script>"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Parameters": {
        "VPCSelection": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
        },
        "WebServerSecurityGroupGroupDescription": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "WebServerInstanceImageId": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Image::Id"
        },
        "WebServerInstanceInstanceType": {
          "Type": "String",
          "Default": "t2.micro",
          "AllowedValues": [
            "",
            "t2.nano",
            "t2.micro",
            "t2.small",
            "t2.medium",
            "t2.large",
            "t2.xlarge",
            "t2.2xlarge",
            "m4.large",
            "m4.xlarge",
            "m4.2xlarge",
            "m4.4xlarge",
            "m4.10xlarge",
            "m3.medium",
            "m3.large",
            "m3.xlarge",
            "m3.2xlarge",
            "m1.small",
            "m1.medium",
            "m1.large",
            "m1.xlarge",
            "c4.large",
            "c4.xlarge",
            "c4.2xlarge",
            "c4.4xlarge",
            "c4.8xlarge",
            "c3.large",
            "c3.xlarge",
            "c3.2xlarge",
            "c3.4xlarge",
            "c3.8xlarge",
            "c1.medium",
            "c1.xlarge",
            "cc2.8xlarge",
            "cc1.4xlarge",
            "g2.2xlarge",
            "g2.8xlarge",
            "cg1.4xlarge",
            "r3.large",
            "r3.xlarge",
            "r3.2xlarge",
            "r3.4xlarge",
            "r3.8xlarge",
            "x1.32xlarge",
            "m2.xlarge",
            "m2.2xlarge",
            "m2.4xlarge",
            "cr1.8xlarge",
            "d2.xlarge",
            "d2.2xlarge",
            "d2.4xlarge",
            "d2.8xlarge",
            "i2.xlarge",
            "i2.2xlarge",
            "i2.4xlarge",
            "i2.8xlarge",
            "hi1.4xlarge",
            "hs1.8xlarge",
            "t1.micro"
          ]
        },
        "WebServerInstanceKeyName": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
          "Default": "default"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Interface": {
          "Key": "AWS::CloudFormation::Interface",
          "ParameterGroups": [
            {
              "Label": {
                "default": "WebServerSecurityGroup Properties"
              },
              "Parameters": [
                "WebServerSecurityGroupGroupDescription"
              ]
            },
            {
              "Label": {
                "default": "WebServerInstance Properties"
              },
              "Parameters": [
                "WebServerInstanceImageId",
                "WebServerInstanceInstanceType",
                "WebServerInstanceKeyName"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "ParameterLabels": {
            "WebServerSecurityGroupGroupDescription": {
              "default": "Description"
            },
            "WebServerInstanceImageId": {
              "default": "Image Id (AMI)"
            },
            "WebServerInstanceInstanceType": {
              "default": "Instance Size"
            },
            "WebServerInstanceKeyName": {
              "default": "Key Name"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```